# how to count all the entries put under a row having specific days of a month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In this Sheet:

[image]

How to count all the entries (Text or Numbers) under A1 to AD1 (based on days only from Sun to Thu.) except Fri and Sat.

Note: if month is changed from list thus all the dates and days will be changed. Counting done as per changed month

Note: if month is changed from list thus all the dates and days will be changed. Counting done as per changed month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given there are two rows at the top of the sheet, I am going to assume you want to check the contents of A3:AD3 against the day of the week in row A1:AD1

My simple answer is this formula at the end of each row (cell AF3, for example)

```
=COUNTIFS(A3:AD3,"=*",A1:AD1,"Sunday")+COUNTIFS(A3:AD3,">0",A1:AD1,"Sunday")+
COUNTIFS(A3:AD3,"=*",A1:AD1,"Monday")+COUNTIFS(A3:AD3,">0",A1:AD1,"Monday")+
...
```

You could also create a hidden helper row (let's call it AD2) that operates on the date row using the WEEKDAY() function, which will generate a number between 1 an 7 for the day of the week starting with Sunday. In this implementation, you would only need the following:

```
=COUNTIFS(A3:AD3,"=*",A2:AD2,"<6")+COUNTIFS(A3:AD3,">0",A2:AD2,"<6")
```

Another solution would be to copy/paste a similar formula across the columns at the top of the sheet (row1, for example), as follows:
=IF(WEEKDAY(A2)<6,COUNTIF(A3:A32768,"=*")+COUNTIF(A3:A32768,">0"),"")
This assumes your date is in row2 and the data entries start in row3. As rows are added to the sheet the formula will work without requiring any action. In this example I used 32768 for the max number of rows but this is arbitrary.
To get the overall total you would sum the across the columns of row1, such as SUM(1:1) or sum (A1:ZZ1) depending on the number of columns you have.

Comment: Good catch on the typo Scott. I forgot the "*". Thanks!

Comment: Thanks dear but this only counts only one row A3 to AD3 but i want to count all the entries down from i.e A3 to AD100  i ve found one =SUM(COUNTIFS($A$1:$AH$1, {"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu"}, D3:AH3,"<>")) but it only works for single row #3 not all the rows  from 3 to onward.

Comment: My assumption was that you would copy that formula for each row and then you can add up the column with the totals

Comment: in that case i have to make helper row/column and addition of new member i have to add up that row with total count. can you please suggest me solution in one formula that count all the rows under the Specified days. Sun to thu.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide an alternative approach that I think addresses your concern. With this approach, the user does not need to do anything when a new row is added to the spreadsheet